# Run command with specific arguments without password as root for all users

Tags: permissions, su, fdisk

I want to be able to run `fdisk -l` as any user, without getting the whole `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied` message.

I don't see how `fdisk -l` can be used for malicious purposes.

I have a PHP script, which first checks if the user is logged into my website, and if they are admin.

Then I have an admin control panel, where it shows the output of `fdisk -l`, however, I am getting the error `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied`.

There is no user input, so they can't inject arguments into the command.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create a program calling `fdisk`. Writing it in C\C++ would be easy, you just need a compiler. Then change the owner of the executable to `root` and give it the `SUID` right (giving the `SUID` to a script won't work that's why you'll need an executable not a script). Make sure no other user can write to that file or it could cause a security issue.